# How you you assign the value of a char pointer to an integer

Tags: c

Is there a way to assign the value of a char pointer to an integer

Comment: What is the effect you want to achieve? Do you want the address in the pointer as an integer? Or do you want to parse the string being pointed to as an integer, or something like that?

Comment: First define what it means to get "the value of a char pointer".

Comment: Please clarify your question by providing example code and data.

Answer (score 3):

Convert to `void *` and then to `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, if one ot these optional types exist

```
intptr_t convert(char *s) [
  void *p = s;
  return (intptr_t) p;
}
```

> 7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers
>
> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>   `intptr_t`
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>   `uintptr_t`
>
> These types are optional.

Comment: Is it actually necessary to convert a `char *` to `void *` first? I suppose if it's OK to convert twice, it should be OK to convert only once. If not, can I just write `return (intptr_t)(void *) p;`?

Comment: @sunqingyao: This is because the standard, technically, only defines the conversion between `void *` and `intptr_t`. In any practical implementation, however, this is very unlikely to actually matter, so I wouldn't be afraid of skipping the cast to `void *`, but if you want to be strictly compliant, you shouldn't. And yes, writing the two casts after oneanother works just as well.

Comment: @sunqingyao  Agree with Dolda2000.  This answer does it explicitly in 2 steps for clarity, yet `return (intptr_t)(void *) p;` is equivalent.

Answer (score -2):

No.  Period.  Full stop.

Unless you like invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: That is only true under the strictest possible interpretation of the standard. If `intptr_t` is defined (which, in practice, it always is), it is defined to be able to hold the value of any pointer such that casting it back to a pointer preserves the original value.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Being strict is just one of the prerequisites to reliable systems.  I will never make any apologies for that.  I've dealt with enough 3 AM calls or last-minute 3,000 mile flights to believe anything else.

Comment: Not every piece of software needs to be built with nuclear-grade reliability, though, honestly. OP might even just be experimenting with pointers to further his understanding of them.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Well, that's why I added the "UB" caveat.

Comment: Yes, well, as I pointed out, that's not true. It would only be true for implementations that lack `intptr_t`. And those don't really exist, outside perhaps something one could dig up from the most esoteric of experiments out there.

Comment: @Dolda2000 What can I say, I have high standards.  I don't like getting called at 3 am.  The question said "integer", which strongly implies `int`.  In my experience, trying to outsmart the people who wrote the language standards isn't worth the trouble.  Which, as you have implicitly added, is why such things as `intptr_t` exist. (and why I upvoted *chux*'s answer - it's strictly more correct than mine)

Comment: "*The question said "integer", which strongly implies `int`.*" -- There is quite a lot that is unclear about the question, even beyond that. I'd hesitate to even answer before OP has replied to the comments.